# PHP Project run correctly in PHPStorm, but run failed by apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I write a PHP file which uses ODBC to query data from MySQL. The project run correctly in PHPStorm.
[image]

However, when I use Apache to visit my php file, some errors come across. First, it could not connect to MySQL; second, the warning information displays in a not proper charset. I've tried to modify the charset of apache, but it doesn't work.

[image: Issues]

My php code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        
        $conn = odbc_connect("MyODBC", "root", "113459");
        if(!$conn){
            exit("Connection failed:".$conn);
        }
        else{
            echo "Connection Successfully! <br/>";
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM persons";
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

        if(!$rs){
            exit("Error in MySQL <br/>");
        }
        else{
            echo "Execute Successfully!<br/>";
        }


        echo "<table><tr>";
        echo "<th>perosnID</th>";
        echo "<th>FirstName</th>";
        echo  "<th>LastName</th>";
        echo  "<th>Age</th>";

        while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
            $personID = odbc_result($rs,"personID");
            $FirstName = odbc_result($rs,"FirstName");
            $LastName = odbc_result($rs,"LastName");
            $Age = odbc_result($rs,"Age");

            echo "<tr><td>$personID</td>";
            echo "<td>$FirstName</td>";
            echo "<td>$LastName</td>";
            echo "<td>$Age</td></tr>";
        }

        odbc_close($conn);

        echo "</table>";

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You said you're using MySQL, why are you using odbc?  mysqli or PDO are much more supported in PHP.

Comment: The method of mysqli or PDO work well. I am a student and am doing my homework. The homework request me use ODBC to visit MySQL.

Comment: Understandable for homework.  Try to clear this up a bit, when you say `run correctly in PHPStorm, but run failed by apache`, are you talking about the same computer?  It looks like you just can't connect to the MySQL server with those parameters, it shouldn't have anything to do with the web server.

Comment: The choice of ODBC is rather odd, it shows up extremely infrequently here. Most PHP MySQL code should default to PDO or something better, so worth checking that out if you ever need to do something else.